# problem when using servlet and web project with java

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

i have just started using servlet. basically i am new to web projects. I am using eclipse as development IDE. In that i have created a dynamic web project, in the same i added one html page viz Main.html with the following sript:_

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>this is the first page</b>
</body>
</html>
```

and following is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>ServletProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

i am using tomcat 6.0 as web container, in eclipse only i have integrated tomcat and have added the web project in it. The server is getting started properly. When i am trying to access the `Main.html` page, i am not getting anything on the browser, in the tomcat server configuration, there are two ports, one is admin port and other is HTML/1.1 port and value is  8005 and 8080 respectively. When i am using `http://localhost:8005/Main.html` i am getting nothing one the web browser, but when i use `http://localhost:8080/Main.html` i get some tomcat error.

is there something i am missing. I am unable to figure it out. Please help me.

Comment: Can you share the error code/error details as well?

Comment: @Faisal : i get some HTTP Status 404 error when i use the second URL as mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: Ah yeah, you need to use the ServletProject as url-pattern..*
Try to access the file with the following URL: http://localhost:8080/ServletProject/Main.html

You need to configure your application properly in the web.xml file and if you want to use later a Java class and use it as a Servlet you have to define this in the web.xml like that:

```
<servlet> 
   <servlet-name>CurrencyConverter</servlet-name> 
   <servlet-class>servlets.Converter</servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>CurrencyConverter</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/convert</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url pattern defines the path you can access it later. To access the CurrencyConverter in the above code you need to use this url: http://localhost:8080/convert

Yeah and it would be good when you could show us the error you get..

Answer (score 2):

The URL should be `http://localhost:8080/ServletProject/Main.html`. Where `ServletProject` is your application context.

Comment: ah u beat me to it, but if he had chosen "Right Click > Run As > Run on Server" within Eclipse - it would have opened the browser with the right URL and worked.

Comment: @JoseK: Yeah. But I am not very familiar with Eclipse. BTW, where is my upvote ;).

Comment: dude, you beat me to the answer, and you want me to reward you for it :) the OP hasnt confirmed this worked yet, hmmm

Comment: @JoseK: Okay! that means you were not sure of your answer, that might made you late ;)

Comment: Nope - I was composing some theory on how "ServletProject" seemed to be the web app context auto-populated by Eclipse into web.xml on creating the project. Thats when I saw the new answer.